# Chrome Extension - declarativeNetRequest remove requestHeader "origin" not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to remove requestHeader 'origin' using declarativeNetRequest. It's not working as the origin is still being sent with SharePoint rest api call. How do we ensure the rule is being triggered or not? How can we troubleshoot the issue?

Here is my manifest.json and rules.json

```
{
  "short_name": "SPO Helper",
  "name": "SPO Helper",
  "icons": {
    "16": "favicon.ico",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo512.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "./static/js/background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": false,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "action": {    
    "default_title": "SPO Helper"
  },
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "./rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "scripting",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.sharepoint.com/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

rules.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "modifyHeaders",
            "requestHeaders": [
                {
                    "header": "origin",
                    "operation": "remove"
                }
            ]
        },
        "condition" : {
            "domains": ["cbgbfoeehbjllcimibeojmpgeoncgjcl"],
            "resourceTypes" : ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
          }
    }
]
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: ManifestV3 is still a steaming pile of bugs.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I figured out the issue, its not a bug.. the "condition" is the problem. If I keep the "condition" as blank everything is working fine. Now the question is how do I apply this rule only when my api call is initiated by this extension? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Since the only way is to have a condition, it's still a bug.

Answer (score 4):

using `onRuleMatchedDebug` you can check if your rule is being triggered.

you must add the `declarativeNetRequestFeedback` permission in your manifest.json and add this in your service worker:

```js
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.addListener(function (o) {
  console.log('rule matched:', o);
});
```